# Copy Gnosis-safe on Ethereum to safe on Polygon with same safe address

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

we followed the instructions here, https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741, to create a safe with the same address as our original safe on Ethereum, on the Polygon network.
Our safe address is 0x7E08C7606aCF5887B7dA9914f7c7cD05c2bec8Ab
The transaction went through and we can see it here: https://polygonscan.com/address/0x7E08C7606aCF5887B7dA9914f7c7cD05c2bec8Ab, but it's not registered as a contract and we can't switch the network in our gnosis safe.
Did we do something wrong ? Or how long will it take before we can access it ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You sent the transaction to the safe address but instead should've sent it to the factory contract, please follow the video carefully.
2. You will not be able to use the Safe in the interface, please check the video description:

> However, existing Safe addresses on Eth mainnet re-created on L2/sidechains (and vice versa) do not load up within our UI. This is because they use different singleton contracts. Therefore, users would need to load these newly created Safes via another UI e.g. through our command line interface: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-cli.

This functionality is only intended for the recovery of funds sent on an incorrect network.

Answer (score 0):

To load the Safe

```
pip3 install -U safe-cli
safe-cli <safe_address> <node_url>
```

To perform actions on that safe:

```
tx-service balances
send_ether <address> <value-wei>
```

See [safe-cli](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-cli) and my [previous answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/144186/92254) for more context.