# How to recover tokens send to Ethereum instead of Polygon (1.3.0)

Tags: gnosis-safe

USDC's were sent to a safe's address, but in the wrong network (did it in Ethereum, should of been done in Polygon). I've managed to deploy the contract on that Eth's address, and managed to view the safe on the safe App, but still the assets don't appear in the App.

I have consulted through the help chat, but instructions are to complex.

Any easy way to recover the tokens?

Comment: What contract have you deployed on that address?

Comment: Check the reply of: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/123289/copy-gnosis-safe-on-ethereum-to-safe-on-polygon-with-same-safe-address

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is through the [safe-cli](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-cli).

```bash
pip3 install -U safe-cli
safe-cli <safe_address> <node_url>
load_cli_owners MY_PRIVATE_KEY_1 MY_PRIVATE_KEY_2
send_ether <address> <value-wei>
```

Why?

> Existing Safe addresses on Eth mainnet re-created on L2/sidechains (and vice versa) do not load up within our UI. This is because they use different singleton contracts. Therefore, users would need to load these newly created Safes via another UI e.g. through our command line interface: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-cli.

[source](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/123294/92254)

You can run that script above to send the tokens from your Safe to your desired network.

Note: You can't send tokens cross-chain so you can send those tokens to your EOA/Metamask account and then bridge them to Polygon. Note that [bridging tokens has risks](https://docs.chain.link/resources/bridge-risks/) so I recommend you do the following:

1. Use safe-cli to send tokens from Safe to EOA/Metamask
2. Bridge from Ethereum to Polygon
3. Swap wrapped/bridged token on Polygon to native Polygon token

Running stuff from the command line can be hard so I made [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/ademidun/003eee3ccdd3daa21943846c05f68b18/safe_cli.ipynb) to make it easy to use safe-cli from your browser. Just click the play arrow beside each cell and it will run it automatically for you.

Note: In the example above I'm assuming that you need 2 signers, thus 2 private keys, to send a transaction. Change the number of private keys based on your Safe rules.

1. For `node_url` you can use https://polygon-rpc.com or https://chainlist.org/ to find other RPC urls for polygon and other networks.